# Python nested loop calculate sum

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have:

**models.py**

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    plant_name = models.CharField()
    multiplier = no_recording = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class Recording(models.Model)
    plant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    no_recording = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def x(self):
        return self.no_recording*self.plant.multiplier
```

I need: the sum of x for every plant. What I tried in my view is this but it does not. I get the 'Recording' object has no attribute 'aggregate'

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    plants = Plant.objects.all()
    total_recording_per_plant = []
    for plant in plants
        for recording in plant.recording_set.all():
         total_recording_per_plant.append(recording.aggregate(sum=Sum('x')))
```

But I get the 'Recording' object has no attribute 'aggregate'

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply aggregations to things that are database fields. `x` as have it define is a method on the model.

```
Recording.objects.values("plant").annotate(
    agg=Sum(F("no_recording")*F("plant__multiplier"),
    output_field=FloatField())
)
```

which should group by plant id the annotate the queryset with the sum of no_recording * plant__multplier

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Comment: I get:  `<QuerySet [{'plant': 1, 'sum': 666.6666666666666}, {'plant': 2, 'sum': 1000.0}, {'plant': 1, 'sum': 666.6666666666666}]>` How can I get only the sum??

Comment: Of all the things? Then remove the .values(plant)

Comment: my **views.py**  `def home(request): plants = Plant.objects.all()
   total_recording_per_plant = []
    for plant in plants
                      total_recording_per_plant = Recording.objects.values("plant").annotate(sum=Sum(F("no_recording") * F("plant__multiplier")))` **and in my html template** `{% for plant in plants %}
                                total_recording_per_plant}}</td>
                            {% endfor %}`  and I get what I wrote in my first comment